# Amazon EC2 Linux SSL certbot-auto "Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper"

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I want to Configure SSL / TLS on Amazon Linux "Using Let's Encrypt with Certbot on Amazon Linux ami / 2018.03-release-notes" as described in [the document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-ami.html) but when I run the

```
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
```

command I have some kind of strange message

[image]

[image]

I don't know what to do anymore, I failed everywhere without success, I don't know if that's the problem.

I have already successfully configured SSL / TLS on Amazon Linux "Using Let's Encrypt with Certbot on Amazon Linux ami / 2018.03-release-notes" as [described in the document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-ami.html) this way and I never got this message.

Please help me.

Comment: that's not an error, just a note that the epel was setup.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to install letsencript on Amazon Linux AMI using certbot and I get the following message:

sudo ./certbot-auto --debug
skipping bootstrap because certbot-auto is deprecated on this system. your system is not supported by certbot-auto anymore. certbot cannot be installed. please visit https://certbot.eff.org/ to check for other alternatives.